# PHP not outputting anything when there are errors

Tags: php

So I just recently updated our company intranet from PHP 5 to PHP 7 and one change I noticed is that 7 no longer outputs anything if there are non-fatal errors on the page.  Consider the following:

```
echo "Hello World";
echo $undefinedVar1;
echo $undefinedVar2;
```

In PHP 5, I would get output such as this:

```
Hello World
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: undefinedVar1 in...
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: undefinedVar2 in...
```

Now, in PHP 7, I only get the two errors, not the "Hello World" line.  It is important to note here, that the code in 7 does NOT halt at the errors since I do get BOTH errors.  I just don't get the Hello World text as I would expect.  This presents an issue when, for example, I have a division by 0 error on a line with a complex formula.  Normally, I'd print out the formula to the screen to see where the 0 error is, but now all I get is the error.  I found that I can use exit; or die(); to kill the script just before the offending line and get my output, but that doesn't work in all situations.  Consider:

```
$x = 10;
$y = 3;
for ($z=0; $z<10; $z++) {
    echo "Attempt $x / $y: ";
    echo ($x/$y)."<br />";
    $y--;
}
```

In 5, I would get this:

```
Attempt 10 / 3: 3.33333333
Attempt 10 / 2: 5
Attempt 10 / 1: 10
Attempt 10 / 0:
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in...
```

And I could see that the fourth loop is causing the problem because $y is reduced to 0.  But in 7, all I get is the error, which tells me nothing other than there's a zero somewhere in the formula.  I can't use exit; or die(); because it'll kill the script on the first iteration of the loop, which has no error.

I've checked my error reporting level (which is: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT in both versions) but I don't know what else to check.  I looked through other php.ini settings, but nothing else really jumped out at me as being relevant. Please help?

Comment: `display_errors = on`

Comment: Also, just to be sure, your php.ini might be one thing, but your code might be another. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/231316

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue is not displaying errors.  It is displaying all the errors I wish it to display.  The problem is that the errors are the ONLY thing it displays when they occur.  That said, I did try those suggestions previously, regarding setting display_errors and the error reporting level within the code itself.  None of it made any difference.